# Rikulo - Which View method called when subviews loaded

Tags: dart, rikulo

Using Rikulo_UI (a Dart library), I have created a custom View subclass, and used it in a UXL template, and added some children Views (Button, TextView, etc.) to it.

Which View method is called after all of it's children defined in UXL have been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[onChildAdded_](http://api.rikulo.org/ui/latest/rikulo_view/View.html#onChildAdded_) was called for each child being added, but there is no special callback to notify all children have been added.